# Error 201 interactive brokers tws while placing options order

Tags: python, error-handling, stock, interactive-brokers, tws

I am trying to place an option order through TWS on a demo account. I followed the tutorial, but when I run the code, it gives me error 201, "The account number is invalid or is missing". I have spent some time trying to fix it but can't seem to tackle it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import *
from threading import Timer

class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error: ", reqId, " ", errorCode, " ", errorString)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId):
        self.nextOrderId = orderId
        self.start()

    def orderStatus(self, orderId , status, filled,
                    remaining, avgFillPrice, permId,
                    parentId, lastFillPrice, clientId,
                    whyHeld, mktCapPrice):
        print("Order Status ID: ", orderId, ", Status", status, ", Fiilled", filled, ", Remaining: ", remaining, ", Last Fill price: ", lastFillPrice)

    def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order,
                  orderState):
        print("OpenOrder ID: ", orderId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, "@", contract.exchange, ":", order.action, order.orderType, order.totalQuantity, orderState.status)

    def execDetails(self, reqId, contract, execution):
        print("ExecDetails. ", reqId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, contract.currency, execution.execId, execution.orderId, execution.shares, execution.lastLiquidity)

    def start(self):

        contract = Contract()
        contract.symbol = "VMW" ##self.symbol
        contract.secType = "OPT"
        contract.exchange = "SMART"
        contract.currency = "USD"
        contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "20200619" #self.expirationDate
        contract.strike = 152.5 #self.strikeP
        contract.right = "C" #self.callorput
        contract.multiplier = "100"

        order = Order()
        order.action = "BUY" #self.buyorsell
        order.totalQuantity = 10
        order.orderType = "MKT"

        self.placeOrder(self.nextOrderId, contract, order)

    def stop(self):
        self.done = True
        self.disconnect()

def main():
    app = TestApp()
    app.nextOrderId = 0

    app.connect(host = 'XXXX', port=XXXX, clientId=X)

    Timer(3, app.stop).start()
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

IB demo accounts often have a partitioned account structure to demo that capability. In a partitioned setup, one part of the account is 'partitioned' for use by a financial advisor while the rest of the account is traded by the account owner. Each part has a unique identifying number used when querying positions or placing trades.

When placing orders to a partitioned account, you would just need to specify the account number where you are sending the order in the IBApi Order class with the other order attributes. E.g.

```
order.account = "DU12345"
```

if the partition available for trading is labelled "DU12345". It may have a 'C' at the end. You should be able to find the account number in the top right of TWS, or through the API `managedaccts()` callback which is invoked automatically after the connection is made.

http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/financial_advisor_methods_and_orders.html#api_orders